# Headers content included in file uploaded in django rest framework

Tags: django, parsing, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue in my django api file upload.
When I upload file using FileUploadParser everything goes well
but the file upload contains the header of the request stuff like Content-Disposition
when i try to open the uploaded file it is broken. I searched for a while for some solution but no chance. Decided to use MultiPartparser but this way nothing is included in the request.data dict. How can I go around this ? Can somebody show me a code or a way to successfully upload file or image to my api without having them broken ? Thanks for any hint.
Here's the code I have so far

```
class EstablishmentMediaUploadView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_class = JSONWebTokenAuthentication
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = MediaSerializer
    name = 'establishment-media-file-upload'

    def put(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        if 'file' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty media file for establishment")
        establishmentid = kwargs.get('establishmentid')
        if establishmentid is None:
            return Response({"error": "You didn't specify the establishmentid"}, status=400)
        mediaFile = request.data.get('file')
        media = Media.objects.create(mediatitle=mediaFile.name)
        establishment = Establishment.objects.get(id=establishmentid)
        media.establishmentlogo.save(mediaFile.name, mediaFile, save=False)
        media.establishment = establishment
        media.save()
        return Response({"message": "Logo added for this establishment"}, status=200)
```

I first test it by uploading from Insomnia api test client and Vscode thunder client extension. For both the headers are included.

Then I did the test in my angular frontend. Here's the code of the service method in charge of the upload :

```
setEstablishmentLogo(establishment: Establishment, media: Media): Observable<Object> {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.set("establishmentlogo", media.establishmentlogo);
    var url = `${endpoints.establishment_media_upload_uri_base}/${establishment.id}`;
    console.log(url)
    return this.http.put(url, formdata, {
      headers: {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=${media.establishmentlogo.name}`,
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
```

Got the same behavior. Perhaps I'm getting something wrong in all this. But can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @FaisalNazik Yes done already.

Answer (score 0):

Well i use flutter framework and i upload images from mobile to django and guess what, it updates image field without doing anything from my end. Just make sure where ever you are uploading this image from do it accordingly to http library in that framework.

Comment: can you please show an example of the way you make http calls to update the imageField ? It could help me

Answer (score 0):

So just to avoid this headache to another folk. Here is what I found finally.

I was using FileUploadParser in my uploadview. But the point is that when using the 'FileUploadParser' the request.data dict
is populated with the uploaded content. The uploaded content in that case, when it comes from clients like Postman
or Insomnia or Thunder Client of vscode, it contains the single file you uploaded (We assume that you select the option binary request
in those clients) and that way, nothing wrong happens, the files are safe. But when you upload files from the browser, let's say from angular and the parser_class in the view is set to FileUploadParser
then you will successfully upload the file but it would be broken because the whole request (file + headers and browser boundaries stuffs) is parsed as a single file
by FileUploadParser(It's indeed it's job) and thus you end up with broken files on your server or backend. So the way to go around that is to set parser_classes to MultipartParser and FormParser optionally
That way your uploaded files are fine. And much, you don't need to specify Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='some file name' in your request header. Bear in mind that when you use FileUploadParser, your file is in request.data['file'] and when it is MultiPartParser (and FormParser) the file is in request.FILES['file'].

With all this said, the working version of the upload view I posted in my question looks like below :

```
class EstablishmentMediaUploadView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_class = JSONWebTokenAuthentication
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    name = 'mtp-establishment-media-file-upload'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'file' not in request.FILES:
            return Response({"message": "Please provide a file"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        establishmentid = kwargs.get('establishmentid')
        if establishmentid is None:
            return Response({"error": "You didn't specify the establishmentid"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        mediaFile = request.FILES['file']
        media = Media.objects.create(mediatitle=mediaFile.name)
        media.establishmentlogo.save(mediaFile.name, mediaFile, save=True)
        try:
            establishment = Establishment.objects.get(id=establishmentid)
        except Establishment.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Establishment does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        media.establishment = establishment
        media.save()
        return Response({"message": "Logo added for this establishment"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`FileUploadParser`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser), make sure to POST raw binary data:

From the command line:

```bash
$ curl -X POST --data-binary '@./video.mp4' -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ignored.mp4' <url>
```

From python:

```py
import requests
requests.post(
    <url>, 
    data=open('./video.mp4', 'rb'),
    headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=ignored.mp4'}
)
```

This raw data will then be either [streamed to disk](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.2/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L70) or [streamed to memory](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.2/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L96), depending on the payload size. You can then iterate over the [chunks](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.2/django/core/files/base.py#L48) of bytes and do something with the data:

```py
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class VideoView(APIView):
    parser_classes = APIView.parser_classes + [FileUploadParser]

    def post(self, request):
        """Handle POST request containing raw binary data.

        Args:
            request: The prepared request from drf.

        Notes:
            Make sure to add the header: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=video.mp4`.
            The filename passed in this header is ignored.
            The Content-Type header is also ignored (*/* is accepted).

        Examples:
            $ curl -X POST --data-binary '@./video.mp4' -H 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ignored.mp4' <url>
            >>> import requests; requests.post(<url>, data=open('./video.mp4', 'rb'), headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=ignored.mp4'})

        References:
            https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

        Returns:
            Response(status=201)
        """
        if "file" not in request.data:
            return Response(
                "Bad data in POST request: expected raw binary data and a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=video.mp4` header",
                status=400,
            )

        chunk_iter = request.data["file"].chunks(1 << 19)  # read 512kB chunks
        for chunk in chunk_iter:
            ...  # do something with these chunks of bytes
```